# Problem starting a React server on Windows and WSL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, git-bash, wsl-2

Our company is using PC's to develop with Node based frameworks and libraries  and I've set everything up using WSL2 and install Git Bash for terminal. When trying to start a React app, I'm getting the following error:

```
 Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\  public\index.html' in 'C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web'
  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\Demian S  ims\projects\ocr-web\public\index.html' in 'C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-  web'
      at C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilat  ion.js:2015:28
      at C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalMo  duleFactory.js:798:13
      at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\node_module  s\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :10:1)
      at C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalMo  duleFactory.js:270:22
      at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\node_module  s\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :9:1)
      at C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalMo  duleFactory.js:434:22
      at C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalMo  duleFactory.js:116:11
      at C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalMo  duleFactory.js:670:25
      at C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalMo  duleFactory.js:855:8
      at C:\Users\Demian Sims\projects\ocr-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalMo  duleFactory.js:975:5
```

Node is definitely installed and I've tried version 18 and 16. I've also tried the usual method of deleting node_modules and running `yarn` again. Nothing. I can't imagine it would be the webpack.config file because it's working for everyone else. Our app is all TSX, BTW.

Comment: Just a heads-up -- If you are using Git Bash (which, from the error messages, it appears you are), then you aren't using WSL2 (at least not at the same time).  Those are two completely separate environments.  Also, for clarity, Git Bash isn't a "terminal", but a shell/application that runs *in* a terminal (usually the same terminal that WSL, PowerShell, and CMD run in).  If you've installed anything (Node modules, etc.) in a WSL2 distribution, it won't be directly accessible from Git Bash.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah bad use of terms. I'm trying to get PC development as Mac like as possible. I could swear I had this working on a previous machine though. I'm using VSCode and running commands from Git Bash within VSCode. We're using Docker to run our Server (locally). And I installed Git Bash because I'm more comfortable with Bash.

Comment: Sure, but most any WSL distribution will include the Bash shell by default.  When you install Git Bash, that's a separate shell that runs *directly* on Windows (no emulation/virtualization/ELF translation/etc.).